# c# CPU graph with a twist

Tags: c#, .net, performance, graph, plot

I'm creating a unique application that will help people monitor their system while giving some useful information. Currently I am due to finish it on monday, but I still have a feature I must implement, it is the cpu usage graph.
what I need is just a simple history graph, the simpler the better, but I need it to have a specific feature : to be able to view a value when a mouse hoovers over a location on the graph. It would make sense to show the cpu load in % at that popup, but what I want to do is to overwrite the percentage, and instead just show the process that used the most cpu time at that time.
here is a screenshot to futher illustrate my wish - http://prntscr.com/5q7no2
I guess I'll be able to query the process at that given moment, but maybe some of you know of an easy and resource aware way to implement such a graph?
The application will be free, and I'll comment a link to it in this question, and one other :)
You guys are the best. Thank you :3 !

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but asking for links/libraries is off-topic on SO. If you decide to edit the post please remove all unrelated text like "by Monday", are the best", "unique application".

Answer (score 1):

You want to be *able to view a value when a mouse hoovers over a location on the graph*

This is simple when you use a [Chart control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To show values with the mouse simply set a [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.tooltip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for each data point:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points[n].ToolTip = percent + "%";
```